# If you paid attention, you’ll do well

Tags: conditionals

As I was watching **The Affair**, I came across a dialogue which seems poor English to me. The dialogue is spoken by a person who is a native American in the series. The dialogue is as follows:

> If you paid attention in class, and done the work, you’ll do well.

First, why is **done** used here and not **did** even though there is no **had** in the conditional sentence?

And secondly, why the result/outcome of the conditional sentence is in future tense (you’ll)?

Comment: It should either be **did** or **had done**. But there is nothing at all wrong with using the future tense at the end of the sentence. One thing happened in the past, and the other thing still hasn't happened yet.

Comment: But what’s the connection between the future tense and the conditional in this dialogue?  Would have made more sense had the sentence been “if you pay attention...do the work...you’ll do well’.

Comment: The conditional is describing something that might or might not have happened in the **past**, not something that's currently taking place in the present. Like this: *If you **paid** attention in class **last week**, you **will do** well on **next week's** test.*

Comment: //First, why is done used here and not did even though there is no had in the conditional sentence?// Even if 'had' was used in the conditional clause,  'done' wouldn't be the correct answer. 2) // why the result/outcome of the conditional sentence is in future tense (you’ll)?//  Unable to make out what the OP means to ask. Is it that "Why the clause that follows the conditional clause is in future tense?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a mess of a sentence, as you surmise.

Here are the possibilities, depending on the context:

At the start of the year, the teacher advises the pupils:

> If you pay attention in class and do the work, you will do well.

Before the exam, the teacher says:

> If you have paid attention in class and done the work, you will do well.

Also possible:

> If you paid attention in class and did the work, you would do well.

After the exam, the teacher advises a disappointed pupil:

> If you had done the work and paid attention in class, you would have done well.

Comment: Is using a future tense at the end a possibility in that dialogue?

Comment: I think Jason Bassford has clarified it above.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not certain what the correct grammar is here, I would like to point out that this show very well could be using poor English on purpose. It is [very common in television to portray Native Americans as poor English speakers](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TontoTalk)--at least it was in older shows. So that is a possibility.